# Writing a function that returns the index of an item in a list when the function parameter is the value of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

had just joined the community and picked up python3 quite recently. Am currently learning through the resource 'How To Think Like A Computer Scientist With Python3, 3rd Edition'. I was working through some exercises on chapter 4: functions and came across this problem:
[Problem in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1vzB.png)

Currently my attempt at the problem is this(please forgive the formatting):

```
print('-----------Ex 2-----------')

days_of_week = ('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday')


def day_name(n):

    if n >= 0 and n < 7:
        return str(days_of_week[int(n)])
    else:
        return 'None'


print(day_name(1))

print('-----------Ex 3-----------')


def num_day(day_name):

    for day in days_of_week:
        if day == day_name:
            return(days_of_week.index(day_name))
        else:
            return 'None'



print(num_day("Tuesday"))
```

For exercise 2 everything seems to be working fine, however with exercise 3 the function returns the index of the day together with 'None' as in here:[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBPyY.png)

Greatly appreciate any explanation on why this occurs and how to remove the presence of the 'None'

Thanks!

Comment: In Ex 3, the method does not return anything. Hence None. 
Instead of print(), return the value.

Comment: besides the explanations given below on what's going on, you could simplify your function `def num_day(day_name):` body to the 1-liner `return days_of_week.index(day_name) if day_name in days_of_week else None`. That makes use of a ternary expression, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/10197418).

Answer (score 1):

In Python, a function always returns None, if you don't specify any return value. So instead of

```
print(days_of_week.index(day_name))
```

You could do

```
return days_of_week.index(day_name)
```

So the actual value you want is returned by your function.

Comment: it should be taken into account that `return days_of_week.index(day_name)` will raise a `ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple` if `day_name` is not in `days_of_week`

Answer (score 0):

What is happening when you call print(num_day("Tuesday")) is that the for loop iterates through the days of the week. So on the first step of the loop, the variable `day` is "Monday". Then the `if` statement is evaluated to false since 'Monday' != 'Tuesday', and so the `else` block is executed, and the function returns `none`, which is not what we wanted. Rather we only want to return `none` after it has iterated through all the week days. So that means we just need to remove the `else` statement, and return `None` only if the input did not match any of the week day names.

```
def num_day(day_name):
    days_of_week = ('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday')
    for day in days_of_week:
        if day == day_name:
            return(days_of_week.index(day_name))
    return 'None'

print(num_day("Tuesday"))
```

Also its better to define the `days_of_week` variable inside the function.

Comment: Ah I see, your explanation definitely helped clarify a few misconceptions. Thanks for sharing your insights!